# Celery chord KeyError with signatures

Tags: python-3.x, celery

I am trying to create a Celery chord to run a task as a callback, ie when others in queue are marked as finished.

The problem is I'm still having this error: `KeyError: 'kwargs'` and I don't manage to know why.

Here is my code:

```
@celery_app.task(
    base=Base,
    bind=True,
    ignore_result=True
)
def callback(self, date=None, queries=[], user_email=None, db_session=None, prestodb_session=None):
    # Do something
    chain(
        another_task.si(user_email=user_email, db_session=db_session),
        group(*tasks)
    ).apply_async()


@celery_app.task(
    base=Base,
    bind=True,
    ignore_result=False
)
def run(self, user_email, pg_session=None, prestodb_session=None):
    chord(
        task1.s(
            user_email=user_email,
            db_session=pg_session
        ),
        task2.s(
            user_email=user_email,
            db_session=pg_session
        ),
        task3.s(
            user_email=user_email,
            pg_session=pg_session,
            prestodb_session=prestodb_session
        )
    )(
        callback.s(
            user_email=user_email,
            date=self.context.run_time,
            db_session=pg_session,
            prestodb_session=prestodb_session
        )
    )
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 382, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 641, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/app/app/tasks/tasks.py", line 87, in run
    prestodb_session=prestodb_session
  File "/home/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 1189, in __call__
    return self.apply_async((), {'body': body} if body else {}, **options)
  File "/home/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 1223, in apply_async
    kwargs = dict(self.kwargs['kwargs'], **kwargs)
KeyError: 'kwargs'
```

I tried all I could: change signature from mutable to immutable, adding *args and **kwargs as parameters in the callback method definition, removing all params bu I still have the issue.

I don't know how I can make this work. Could you help me? Thanks!!

--

Python version: 3.6
Celery version: 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I can't comment yet.
How are you running the `run` task?
I think the issue might be with one of your tasks, I tried something similar with just a simple task that prints a string and it works.

Do you see something getting executed? Maybe the chord?

Comment: You should also try to set `ignore_result=True` on both tasks.